# How to set global proxy programatically in Windows 10

Tags: proxy, settings, windows-10, global

I need to write a program to set proxy for all browsers and all users on a machine for Internet filtering.  Hopefully this is a registry setting I can set.  We used to do this on older versions of Windows but the registry keys must have changed for Windows 8 and 10.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google is wonderful:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384069(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's for Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008